# Using paragraphs 8.5.3p4 and p5 in the C++11 Standard, how do I prove that the snippet below doesn't compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

Using paragraphs 8.5.3p4 and p5 in the C++11 Standard, how do I prove that the snippet below doesn't compile?

```
char a = 'a';
char* p = &a;
const char* & r = p;
```

Comment: I would say "Because of paragraphs 8.5.3p4 and p5 in the C++11 Standard, the following doesn't compile."

Comment: You look up the references given, and think about it; that way, you'll learn something from your homework.

Comment: at least, first, you should not use "char*" to point a constant string.

Comment: You don't, you instead look up the paragraph that says converting the type of `"hello"` (`const char [6]`) to `char*` is illegal. :)

Comment: unless you state what you don't understand about these paragraphs and why you haven't found your solution yourself, I will downvote you because it sounds like "I don't understand the spec, but I will ask nontheless what the spec says in these paragraphs because it's the cool thing these days".

Comment: @user2337207, Any C++11 compiler that accepts it is non-conforming in that regard. At least most give a warning if you let them.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'd say that I'm very familiar with the alluded paragraphs, but I couldn't find one specific reason to justify this behavior. Just to give you an idea: it´s clear to me that T1 = const char* and T2 = char* are different types, and so T1 is not reference-related to T2. But that is not enough to prove that const char* doesn't bind to char*. The last bullet point in 8.5.3p5 has to be verified.

Comment: @user2337207 these explanations should be part of your question. i understand that you might feel that they are redundant (because people that are able to answer you must already know them), but it shows that you have investigated time and actually can evaluate the answer given by people.

Comment: @user2337207 It compiles does not mean it's ok. you can compile any new-but-not-delete code without even a warning, but it leaks.

Comment: @user2337207: In C++ as of C++11, the conversion from a string literal to `char*` is illegal. End of story. It used to be allowed in C++03 and prior, but it is no longer okay. If your compiler allows it, it is an error (either a compiler bug or a missing C++11 feature).

Comment: `char* p = 'h'` won't even compile. How hard would it be to include the relevant sections of the standard that you are referring to?

Comment: Put the relevant parts in your _question_ where they _belong_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, a common mistake in reading 8.5.3p5 is to miss that it has **two** top level bullet points.  You may have accidentally misread the final occurence of "Otherwise" as a third bullet point - but it is in fact a subpart of the second bullet point (also starting Otherwise).

```
char a = 'a';
char* p = &a;
```

OK

```
const char* & r = p;
```

So we have a lvalue-reference to `cv1 T1 = pointer to const char` being bound to an lvalue of type `cv2 T2 = pointer to char`

The two types are not reference-related or reference-compatible.

`cv1` and `cv2` are both empty.

The initializer expression does not have a class type

`cv1` is not const.

Therefore, neither of the two bullet points in 8.5.3p5 apply, and the code is ill-formed.

The two bullet points are:

> 1. If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression... [CONDITIONS FAIL TO APPLY]
> 2. Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const [IT ISNT]), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference [IT ISNT].